# Force jwt token expiration at midnight

Tags: jwt, lexikjwtauthbundle

I have a Symfony application that uses `lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle`. Can I set configuration to force expiration after midnight?

How can I force expiration date at midnight of current day?

Answer (score 0):

The right thing to do is to [read the documentation](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/2-data-customization.md#example-override-token-expiration-date-calculation-to-be-more-flexible). Where they says to ...

1. Add a listener

> ```
>   services:
>         acme_api.event.jwt_created_listener:
>             class: AppBundle\EventListener\JWTCreatedListener
>             arguments: [ '@request_stack' ]
>             tags:
>                 - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: lexik_jwt_authentication.on_jwt_created, method: onJWTCreated }
> ```

2. and put some code inside it

> ```
> <?php
>
> namespace AppBundle\EventListener;
>
> use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Event\JWTCreatedEvent;
>
> class JWTCreatedListener
> {
>     public function onJWTCreated(JWTCreatedEvent $event)
>     {
>         $expiration = new \DateTime(date('d-m-Y'));
>         $expiration->add(new DateInterval('PT86400S'))
>
>         $payload        = $event->getData();
>         $payload['exp'] = $expiration->getTimestamp();
>
>         $event->setData($payload);
>     }
> }
> ```